# Verb for being part of a team

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

One can *lead* a team. But what verb is best used for not leading but just being part of the team? That is, what verb belongs in the blank in the following sentence:

> One can **_** a team.

I am considering *support* or *join*.

Comment: If you support you do not have to be a member. If you join you are. You can also belong to it

Comment: Actually, that particular blank can be filled with a simple *be*. "One can be in a team".

Answer (score 2):

If you are a member, that would be to participate on a team.
'to join a team' would be a one time event, like being transferred from one team to another.
Participating is something more regular basis.

Comment: "Participate a team" doesn't make sense.  Do you mean "participate *on* a team?

Comment: @Kristina: "Participate on [or in] a team".

Answer (score -1):

If it is between participation and leadership, what about *assist*?